# Xbox 360 Arcade Won't Turn On After RROD?

Tags: xbox-360

As the question suggests..

I have an Old White Xbox 360 Arcade that recently RRODed on me. I left the system aside for a while to allow it to cool, and then get the error code. When I decided to switch it back on to get the code, the power brick LED went red and the console didn't start up whatsoever. Why is this? Did the RROD somehow fry the power cable? Or is it possible the RROD warped and bent the motherboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Xbox Support pages](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/console/check-power-supply):

> Flashing orange, solid red, or no light: Your power supply may need to be replaced. Try the following solutions:
>
> 1. Plug your console’s power supply into a different electrical outlet. Do not use a surge protector.
> 2. If the power supply light is solid red or flashing orange, unplug the power supply and let it cool for 30 minutes. Then, plug the power
>      supply back into the outlet.
>
> If your power supply light is still flashing orange, solid red, or
>   unlit, your power supply needs to be replaced.

Its possible that your power supply is no longer functioning correctly.  If the power supply wasn't working properly, it is also possible that it could have fried something in the Xbox, since fluctuating or abnormal power levels have the chance of doing that.

As for the red ring of death, there are [numerous things that it could be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360_technical_problems).  If you are getting the infamous three red lights, its considered a "General Hardware Failure." No error code should pop up on the screen if this is the case.  You said you attempted to get a code, but could not get the unit to power.  If this is the case, you may be experiencing one red light, which is considered a "Hardware Failure."  A code should display on the screen if this is the case.  For two lights, it means the console is overheating.  It should turn off, and the fans will continue to run while the unit cools.  If you have four lights, check your AV connection (if connected this way).  You shouldn't see this error with an HDMI connection.

In any event that there is a hardware failure, its likely the console cannot be saved unless sent for a repair.

Comment: See. Thats interesting. I was told to get a code from the flashing red lights on my console, and then compare it on a site to get the exact error in the system. My console had 3 rings before it died on me.

Comment: @GipsyD [Check out this article](https://www.ifixit.com/Wiki/Xbox_360_Troubleshooting).  I'm wondering if they meant to try the steps under the `Obtaining secondary error codes` section.  However, that requires turning the console on, something I thought you can't do currently?

Comment: Yea. I was told, by their guide, to leave the console for some time, and switch it back on some time later in the event of the RROD, but I couldn't because it didnt switch on either which way. That made getting the code a lot more difficult

Comment: Now that I look at it. I think it was meant to be a secondary code, as they told that I have to get a 4 digit code to compare

Comment: @GipsyD on the Wikipedia page I have linked in my answer, at the very bottom under the [secondary error code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360_technical_problems#Secondary_Error_Code) section, it reads: `An error code of 0001 may represent a defect in the power supply, rather than the Xbox itself, or a short within the Xbox, or a blown capacitor.`

Comment: Now that is starting to sound like the root of the cause. Thanks again for all the insight! It really does help